# Where to catch a KeyboardInterrupt in unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm UI testing on mobile devices using an Appium server. I want to be able to cancel the testing process while developing the tests. Currently, when I `CTRL-C` out of the process (the python unittest), I have to restart the appium server, since the session was not shut down properly (this would have been done in the `tearDown()` method of the test, but since I press CTRL-C, that won't be executed.) Instead I wanna have the `tearDown()` fire everytime the test gets canceled by a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Now's my question: Where do I put the try-catch block to achieve this? Is there a best practice handling this in Python unittests? I need to access a class variable (`self.driver.quit()`), right after `KeyboardInterrupt` fires. The class variable is inside the class that was put into the `unittest.TestSuite` that the `unittest.TextTestRunner` is running.

```
try:
  self.test_something()
except KeyboadInterrupt:
  self.driver.quit()
```

I've looked a bit into `unittest.TestResult` and its `stop()` method but haven't found practical examples explaining its usage properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default behaviour of Python regarding SIGINT to suit your needs:

```
import signal

def my_ctrlc_handler(signal, frame):
    driver_class.quit()
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_ctrlc_handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom TestCase that ensures that `tearDown()`, `tearDownClass()`, and `tearDownModule()` are all run if a test is cancelled with `Ctrl-C`. It also ensures that `tearDown()` etc. all run if *any* exception is raised in `setUp()`.

### Code

```
class SafeTestCase(TestCase):
    """
    SafeTestCase makes sure that tearDown / cleanup methods are always run when
    They should be.
    """

    def run(self, result=None):
        test_method = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
        wrapped_test = self._cleanup_wrapper(test_method, KeyboardInterrupt)
        setattr(self, self._testMethodName, wrapped_test)

        self.setUp = self._cleanup_wrapper(self.setUp, BaseException)

        return super().run(result)

    def _cleanup_wrapper(self, method, exception):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return method(*args, **kwargs)
            except exception:
                self.tearDown()
                self.doCleanups()
                raise

        return wrapped
```

### Usage

To use this, just make sure your `TestCase`s inherit from `SafeTestCase` instead of `unittest.TestCase`.

### Example

```
class MyTestCase(SafeTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        print('setUpClass entered')
        print('setUpClass exited')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        print('tearDownClass entered')
        print('tearDownClass exited')

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        print('setUp entered')
        # raise ValueError()  # tearDown() and tearDownClass() will still run
        print('setUp exited')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown entered')
        foo = 1
        print('tearDown exited')

    def test_test(self):
        print('test entered')
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()   # tearDown() and tearDownClass() will still run
        print('test exited')
```

will print something like

```
setUpClass entered
setUpClass exited
setUp entered
setUp exited
test entered
tearDown entered
tearDown exited
tearDownClass entered
tearDownClass exited
```

and switching which exception is commented will print something like

```
setUpClass entered
setUpClass exited
setUp entered
tearDown entered
tearDown exited
tearDownClass entered
tearDownClass exited
```

### Caveats

- All tearDown methods MUST be idempotent. It's possible a step of tearDown
  will run without it's corresponding setUp having run.
- If an exception is raised in SetUpClass or SetUpModule, tearDowns will
  not be run. (Working around this involves making a custom TestSuite which
  will be ignored if you run tests through PyCharm.)